# Concat attributes

Tags: group-concat

```
    id       key         value
   -----    --------     -----------
    1        first_name  Muhammad
    2        last_name   Muzaffar
    3        color       Red
```

how i can get first_name,last_name values like this

```
Name
Muhammad Muzaffar
```